# Which method is called when tableview is stopped forcely by Scrolling?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am having tabelview with some values and scrolling it fastly.I stopped scorlling by tapping on tableview and I want to know indexpath of cell where I touched.How can I get this?
I called Scorll view delegates method

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
// this method is called using scrollview delegates
}
```

but it is returning always top visible row's indexpath and value.
Please Help!

Comment: Getting touch point on tableview then add it in tableView content offset that`s your y.Then using CGPoint you can find cell. May be these one helps you.

Comment: In which method I can get touch point?

Comment: you can get touch by inherit UITableView Class and in that class you can set firstResponder all touch-methods and get touch points.

Answer (score 0):

Get your response and save it in a dictionary.

NSDictionary *u = [results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Create a button on the scroll view and set a tag value =indexPath.row

On clicking the button while scrolling you get the index of that cell (button here) clicked.